# Simple C Coding Problem: Skipping Over Printf and Skipping User Input

Tags: c, integer, return, printf, program-entry-point

https://onlinegdb.com/-9jZX-uU0 [link]

I want to have the second line of code to have the user input the Fahrenheit not the Celsius twice. The int main() code is correct and the output number is correct but the user does not input the Fahrenheit. How do I fix this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZbtC.png)

What is expected is that the user inputs the Fahrenheit and the code continues. I do not want the output to skip over lines 12-14. I don't know how to fix this. I expect that once the user inputs Fahrenheit the code will continue to run as it currently does

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double ask_for_air_celcius()

{
double temp_celcius, temp;

printf("Enter the current air temperature(in Celcius): ");
scanf(" %lf", &temp_celcius);
return(temp_celcius);

printf("Enter the current air temperature(in Fahrenheit): ");
scanf(" %lf", &temp);
return (temp);
}


int main()


{

double temp_celcius, spsound_1,spsound_convert_1,temp, 
spsound,spsound_convert;

{
    temp_celcius = ask_for_air_celcius(); 
    spsound_1 = 1086 * sqrt(((5 * (temp_celcius*1.8+32)) + 297) 
     / 247);
    spsound_convert_1=spsound_1*1.09728;
    
    temp = ask_for_air_celcius(); 
    spsound = 1086 * sqrt(((5 * temp) + 297) / 247);
    spsound_convert=spsound*1.09728;
    
    printf("\nThe speed of sound at %.2f degrees Celcius is %.2f 
    ft/s.\n", temp_celcius, spsound_1);
    printf ("The speed of sound at this temperature in Celciusis 
    equivalent to %.2f km/h.\n\n", spsound_convert_1);
   printf("The speed of sound at %.2f degrees Fahrenheit is %.2f 
   ft/sec.\n", temp, spsound);
   printf ("The speed of sound at this temperature in Fahrenheit 
   is equivalent to %.2f km/h.\n", spsound_convert);
    }
   return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not a link.

Comment: Write a function for each temperature scale, or have a single function which has the name of the type you want as a parameter.

Comment: Think a little bit: How can a function return two values? What happens when the code reaches an explicit `return` statement?

Comment: I have changed the return statement to both temp and temp_celcius and I cant seem to figure out how to use this function to properly format the code.

Comment: You call `ask_for_air_celcius` twice, and it inputs the Celsius both times, ignoring the Fahrenheit part of the function.

Comment: If I use a new variable called ask_for_air and then call for it using temp=ask_for_air, all the formatting is messed up and I have no idea how to fix it from there:  https://onlinegdb.com/p6M91960F

Comment: `double ask_for_air_fahrenheit() { /* TODO: Get only the Fahrenheit temperature and return it */ }`. Then call `ask_for_air_celcius` ***once***, and `ask_for_air_fahrenheit` once as well. That't the simple and naive solution.

Answer (score 2):

You used used `return` twice in the function so that it `won't go ahead` for asking the fahrenhiet question. Whenever `return` is encountered while compiling it terminates the function there and there only.

Now what you can do is that just make another `function` for fahrenhiet and copy paste the fahrenhit part in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double ask_for_air_celcius(){
    double temp_celcius;
    printf("Enter the current air temperature(in Celcius): ");
    scanf(" %lf", &temp_celcius);
    return(temp_celcius);
}

double ask_for_air_Fahrenhiet(){
    double temp;
    printf("Enter the current air temperature(in Fahrenheit): ");
    scanf(" %lf", &temp);
    return (temp);
}

int main()


{

double temp_celcius, spsound_1,spsound_convert_1,temp, 
spsound,spsound_convert;

{
    temp_celcius = ask_for_air_celcius(); 
    spsound_1 = 1086 * sqrt(((5 * (temp_celcius*1.8+32)) + 297) 
     / 247);
    spsound_convert_1=spsound_1*1.09728;
    
    temp = ask_for_air_Fahrenhiet();//changes here 
    spsound = 1086 * sqrt(((5 * temp) + 297) / 247);
    spsound_convert=spsound*1.09728;
    
    printf("\nThe speed of sound at %.2f degrees Celcius is %.2f ft/s.\n", temp_celcius, spsound_1);
    printf ("The speed of sound at this temperature in Celciusis equivalent to %.2f km/h.\n\n", spsound_convert_1);
    printf("The speed of sound at %.2f degrees Fahrenheit is %.2f ft/sec.\n", temp, spsound);
    printf ("The speed of sound at this temperature in Fahrenheit is equivalent to %.2f km/h.\n", spsound_convert);
}
   return(0);
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!
;)